# How to call AWS API Gateway from C# / .net core

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

I want to call AWS api gateway from my C# code using AWS SDK. I notice the class [AWSSDK.APIGateway](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/) but I am unable to get usage instructions for this library.

Is there a sample available for this nuget package so that I can refer to it as my starting point.

Thanks,